# Fsolve. Function call not proper aray of floats or mismatch between input and output

Tags: scipy-optimize

I have been through the multiple answers available on here and through the scipy documentation but cannot resolve my problem.

I am trying to find the root of my equation and each time I come up with a different error.

```
def func(x):

    return [sgr*(np.exp(-q*(x/p1)**(1/p2))+np.exp(-alpha*(x/p1)**(1/p2))
        -np.exp(-(q+alpha)*(x/p1)**(1/p2)))
        +sveg*(1-np.exp(-q*(x/p1)**(1/p2)))-sfor]
initialGuess=[0]
root = fsolve(func, initialGuess)
```

gives "result from function call is not a proper array of floats"

```
def func(arguments):
    x1 = arguments[0]
    x2 = arguments[1] 
    x3 = arguments[0]
    x4 = arguments[1]     

    return [sgr*(np.exp(-q*(x1/p1)**(1/p2))+np.exp(-alpha*(x2/p1)**(1/p2))
        -np.exp(-(q+alpha)*(x3/p1)**(1/p2)))
        +sveg*(1-np.exp(-q*(x4/p1)**(1/p2)))-sfor]
initialGuess=np.array([0,0,0,0])
root = fsolve(func, initialGuess)
```

gives "shape should be (4,) but it is (1,)"

and

```
def func(arguments):
    x1 = arguments[0]
    x2 = arguments[1] 
    x3 = arguments[0]
    x4 = arguments[1]     

    return [sgr*(np.exp(-q*(x1/p1)**(1/p2))+np.exp(-alpha*(x2/p1)**(1/p2))
        -np.exp(-(q+alpha)*(x3/p1)**(1/p2)))
        +sveg*(1-np.exp(-q*(x4/p1)**(1/p2)))-sfor]
initialGuess=np.array([0,0,0,0])
root = root(func, initialGuess, method='lm')
```

gives "Improper input: N=4 must not exceed M=1"

Is anyone able to assist?

All the other variables have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, a colleague proposed including all the variables in the equation to be solved and it has worked.

```
def func(x, args):
    sgr = args[0]#0.04114
    q = args[1]#0.077673
    p1= args[2]#4.79914
    p2= args[3]#1.0158
    sveg = args[4]#0.052059
    sfor = args[5]#0.0509 #can vary between sveg and sgr
    alpha = args[6]#0.46
    return sgr*(numpy.exp(-q*(x/p1)**(1/p2))+numpy.exp(-alpha*(x/p1)**(1/p2))- 
     numpy.exp(-(q+alpha)*(x/p1)**(1/p2)))+sveg*(1-numpy.exp(-q*(x/p1)**. 
     (1/p2)))-sfor



sgr = 0.06542
q = 0.19782
p1 = 2.67834
p2 = 3.8795
sveg = 0.03962
sfor = 0.0586 
alpha = 0.95

params = [sgr, q, p1, p2, sveg, sfor, alpha]
print("With default parameters:")
print(fsolve(func, 100, params)[0])
print("")
```